# PHP5 foreach $_POST throwing error?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: stristr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /nfs/c09/h03/mnt/12345/domains/mydomainname.com/html/inyoni/fabrics.php
>   on line 385

from this code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {

    if ($value && (stristr($value,"Content-Type: "))){
    header("Location: error.php");
    exit;
    }

}
```

and I have no idea why. In fact, I don't see the error, but my client does. My understanding is that this happens when an image file was included in the form (however, this error didn't appear before, only now).

The site is hosted on Mediatemple and a PHP notification had been sent out to customers about the time this started about PHP5 being used across the board on their servers--is this a PHP5 conflict or something?

A bit puzzled--any help appreciated!

Comment: did you check that all the $value returned are strings?

Comment: error_reporting on & off stuff for all warning visibility issue

Comment: The answer is right there: `expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. It's saying that the first parameter of `stristr()` has to be a string. However, you're supplying an array instead which is why the code produces an error. To fix it, simply make sure you're just checking for string values.

```
if (is_string($value))
{
    if (stristr(...))
}
```

Comment: Doh...that's absolutely right. I had added a checkbox array to an earlier version and did not take arrays vs strings into account here.

Nice catch, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well the `$value` contains an array, not a string. This can happen when you have a form something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="form[foo]"/>
<input type="text" name="form[bar]"/>
```

The `$_POST['form']` will hold an array of those two variables. Check if something like this occurs.

It can also happen with file uploads, multiple checkboxes, etc.

As Kemal Fadillah suggested, make a simple type check of the `$value` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `var_dump($value)` in the loop. If any of the forms contains an array, such as an uploaded file http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php or a bunch of checkboxes, then `$value` would be an array, instead of a string.